# disproving the set is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for a neat prove for If the closure of a set in $R$
is connected
too

Can you help ..

(concise explanition may help me)

Comment: The closure of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is a counterexample.

Comment: What's the statement you want to disprove? "If $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ such that the closure of $A$ is connected, then $A$ is connected for all $n\in\mathbb N$", or is it "There is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that if $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ has a connected closure, then $A$ is connected"? Because in the former case, it's perfectly fine to give $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R=\mathbb R^1$ as a counterexample. If it's the latter, just take $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb R^{n-1}$, the proof is then the same as for $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: How would you do it for $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$? You said that one was easy. For $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb R^{n-1}\subset\mathbb R^n$ it's only a very slight variation.

Comment: The sets $ ( (-\infty,\sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{2},\infty) ) \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ are open, disjoint and contain $ \mathbb{Q}^{n}$.

Comment: Look at the one answer you have by now. It explains exactly that.

Comment: @samuelVAN. You need to do some work yourself. If you can show that the closure of the rations is the reals you can extend this to the $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @samuelVAN. Since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is a sequence $q_k \to x$ where $q_k \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ we see that any closed set containing $ \mathbb{Q}^n$ must contain $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}^n$ seems good to me.  You just need to show that there's a point with rational coordinates arbitrarily close to any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Given $\varepsilon>0$, for each $1\leq k\leq n$ there is a $y_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mid x_k-y_k\mid<\frac\varepsilon n$.  The let $=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n).$  We have $\mid x-y\mid<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @samuelVAN. I don't understand what you are trying to say.  What is supposed to equal $\emptyset$?  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so I can read what you're writing.